# Jasmine-node expect not executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine-node

I started testing today with Jasmine, which is new to me. Since I am working with a GraphQL-server, developed with NodeJS, I am using `jasmine-node`.

The following is my first spec I write myself, and I thought it was working:

```
const request = require('request');
const config = require('../sources/config');

const base_url = `http://localhost:${config.graphqlPort}/${config.graphqlRoute}`;

describe("GraphQLServer.", () => {
it("Should expect something.", () => {
    expect(1).not.toEqual(2);
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    expect(false).not.toBe(true);
});

describe('When request is made.', () => {
    it('Returns statuscode 200.', () => {
        request.get(base_url, (error, response, body) => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            console.log(base_url);
            console.log('StatusCode: ', response && response.statusCode);
            console.log('Body:', body);
            expect(true).toBe(true);
            expect(true).toBe(false);
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);
            done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This gives the following result:

```
    ..

Finished in 0.018 seconds
2 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped


Error:  null
http://localhost:8000/graphql
StatusCode:  400
Body: {"errors":[{"message":"Must provide query string."}]}
```

A lot of this is exactly what I expect. I do a request without a query-string, so the errors in body are expected.

The problem is: the 4 useless (obvious) `expects` inside `it("Should expect something")` are working just fine. Those are the `4 assertions` in the result. The other 4 `expect`'s inside `it("Returns statuscode 200.")` are simply not in the result (they don't fail and they don't pass), but the `console.log`'s are.

Every example I find online seems to do exactly what I do right here, yet I don't manage to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget the exact syntax in Jasmine to suggest a fix, but I believe I know the answer: This is a classic case of testing with promises.  The result is coming back after the test is done, so your `expect` calls are not happening in a context where they can affect the test anymore.

One difference I noticed between your code and the jasmine-node docs is that the function being passed to `it` should take `done` as a parameter, but you have `() =>` instead of `(done) =>`.  That might cause the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kev! I honestly didn't see that silly mistake. I have to admit that I started developing in Javascript only a few weeks ago, so I guess I lack the experience to find such bugs fast. Javascript isn't exactly helping with it's habit of not giving an error is it doesn't need to ;). But thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!  It's true, many JS contexts yield the worst feedback for errors, it can really be maddening sometimes.  Glad to help out!

Answer (score 2):

Kev is right, but the syntax in Jasmine involves putting your expect statement in the promise result, after async execution completion. It would look something like this:

```
it ("should do a thing with promises", function(done) {
            myObject.doAThingWithPromises('')
                .then(function (promiseResult) {
                    expect(promiseResult).toBeDefined();
                    done();
                })
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Elliot for your elaboration :)

Comment: So in this case, `request.get(...).then( () => { ... done() } )`